# Cannot connect to TFS with Eclipse (OSX)

Tags: eclipse, macos, tfs, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to connect to our TFS with the Eclipse Plugin using this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155782(v=vs.120).aspx

Unfortunately I get different error messages (depending on what I do):

#### #1

URL: http://< my TFS-URL >/tfs
Result: "The soap endpoint /Servies/v1.0/Registration.asmx could not be contacted. HTTP status: 404"

#### #2

URL: http://< my TFS-URL >/tfs/DefaultCollection
Result: "Basic credentials are only supported over HTTPS secure connections"

#### #3

URL: https://< my TFS-URL >/tfs (doesn't matter if DefaultCollection is there or not)
Result after about 2 minutes of waiting - I can't login at all: "Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?"

The URL and the credentials are 100% right, I can connect in the browser but it wont work with Eclipse.

We are using TFS2013 and my plugin version is 14.0.2.2015... if that is somewhat important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is staring you in the face:

> URL: http:///tfs/DefaultCollection Result: "Basic credentials are only supported over HTTPS secure connections"

You need to either set up TEE to not care if you send credentials over plain-text (**which is bad** and I strongly recommend against, but can be accomplished by setting the `com.microsoft.tfs.client.allowInsecureBasic` environment variable), or set up HTTPS.

Enabling Basic authentication and setting up HTTPS is something your TFS administrator will have to do.

There are other options (like Kerberos authentication) if you have your Mac joined to a Windows domain, but HTTPS + Basic authentication is probably the easiest if you don't.

Comment: Is there anything to do on the fly? I understand that plain-text is not recommend but I will not be able to achieve the other ways currently.

I tried setting the environment var and printenv shows me that the variable is set to true but I still get the same message.

Comment: Meanwhile I managed to get it working without using plain-text (which for obvious reasons should always be done like that). Thanks for your help!