# Connect to local TFS with java API

Tags: java, tfs

I'm trying to connect to an on-site TFS server using the java API. I have no issues connecting to a VisualStudio online server, but when I try with local, it tells me "Basic credentials are only supported over HTTPS secured connections." Making the server HTTPS is not an option. I've looked at the source code for the Jenkins TFS plugin, and it appears to me that they are using the same authentication as me. Any advice on how to get this connected would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If turning off SSL is no option, then enabling Basic Auth may be an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Daniel Mann's reply in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35831892/cannot-connect-to-tfs-with-eclipse-osx) case:

"
You need to either set up TEE to not care if you send credentials over plain-text (which is bad and I strongly recommend against, but can be accomplished by setting the com.microsoft.tfs.client.allowInsecureBasic environment variable), or set up HTTPS.

Enabling Basic authentication and setting up HTTPS is something your TFS administrator will have to do.

There are other options (like Kerberos authentication) if you have your Mac joined to a Windows domain, but HTTPS + Basic authentication is probably the easiest if you don't."

Answer (score 0):

Responding to an old question with an accepted answer, but I've recently been bit by this and have found a working solution.

Echo the cautions about basic auth over HTTP here, but like OP HTTP is not an option for me.

The setting to disable the warning is not an environment variable, but rather a Java property.  You cannot simply

```
export "com.microsoft.tfs.client.allowInsecureBasic=true"
```

If you are using the tf command line client, you can:

```
export TF_ADDITIONAL_JAVA_ARGS="-Dcom.microsoft.tfs.client.allowInsecureBasic=true"
```

Otherwise (eg, you're using the API), you need to set the property in your Java environment.